# using htmlentities with superglobal variables

Tags: php

I'm working on php with a book now. The book said I should be careful using superglobal variables, so it's better to use htmlentities like this.

```
$came_from = htmlentities($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

So, I wrote a code like this;

```
<?php
    $came_from=htmlentities($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    echo $came_from;
?>
```

However, the display of the code above was the same without htmlentities(); It didn't change anything at all. I thought that it would change \ into something else. Did I use it wrong?

Comment: Why would you expect it to encode "\"?

Comment: No, you did it correctly, it's just that `htmlentities` will only escape values if they need to be escaped - it's a security thing. So if there's nothing that needs to be escaped, then it will be the same.

Comment: BTW you only need to use `htmlentities` (or `htmlspecialchars`) if you plan to output that value at some point as part of your page. If you're just checking it within your PHP code then it doesn't matter. Usually it's more relevant for `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Comment: But I do see that you're echoing it here, so if that's not just test code that you plan to remove later, then you should indeed be using `htmlentities` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

So, by default, [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/function.htmlentities.php) encodes characters using `ENT_COMPAT` (converts double-quotes and leave single-quotes alone) and `ENT_HTML401`. Seeing as the backslash isn't part of the HTML 4.01 entity spec (as far as I can see anyway), it won't be converted.

If you specify the `ENT_HTML5` flag, you get a different result

```
php > echo htmlentities('abc\123');
abc\123

php > echo htmlentities('abc\123', ENT_HTML5);
abc&bsol;123
```

This is because backslash is part of the HTML5 spec. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. My previous answer was absolutely wrong. I was confused with something else. My apologise. Let me refrain my answer:

htmlentities will convert special characters into their HTML entity. "<" for example will be converted to "<". Your browser will automaticly recognise this HTML entity and decode it back to "<". So you won't notice any difference.

The reason for this is to prevent problems when saving your document in something different then UTF-8 encoding. Any characters not encoded might become screwed up for this reason.

Comment: This is completely incorrect in regards to what `htmlentities()` does. `htmlentities()` / `htmlspecialchars()` is used to **encode** [HTML entities](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref), usually to sanitize content output in an HTML document. It has absolutely nothing to do with *"confusing your PHP server"*

Comment: I'd say the biggest use of HTML encoding is to avoid XSS vulnerabilities